# Merging figure or subplot objects

Tags: python, matplotlib

I do want to create two image objects with mathplotlib via separate functions. And I want to merge those images in one image.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot1():

   fig = plt.figure()
   plt.plot([1, 2], [1, 2], '-',color=(0,100/256,170/256))

   return fig

def plot2():

   fig = plt.figure()
   plt.plot([1, 2], [0, 3], '-',color=(0.5,0.5,0.5))

   return fig

fig = plt.figure()
fig1 = plot1
fig2 = plot2
```

Resulting in two images:

```
fig1.show()
fig2.show()
```

But how to combine those?

```
fig(fig1,fig2); fig.show()
```

The challenge is that I do not want to directly access (x,y) values -- only through the functions. So something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x**2)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('Sharing Y axis')
ax2.scatter(x, y)

fig.show()
```

will not do it, as of my humble small knowledge base I have so far. Thx for any help.

Comment: Thx a lot -- made my day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by merge you mean plotting both the lines/functions in a single figure, just define your `plt.figure` object once. After plotting, you don't need to return any object as the plotting will be done in the figure object defined *once* outside the function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()

def plot1():
   plt.plot([1, 2], [1, 2], '-',color=(0,100/256,170/256))
   return 

def plot2():
   plt.plot([1, 2], [0, 3], '-',color=(0.5,0.5,0.5))
   return 

plot1()
plot2()
```

[image]

Another option would be

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
```

and then use `axes` to plot inside your functions as

```
axes.plot([1, 2], [1, 2], '-',color=(0,100/256,170/256))
```

This will further allow you to modify the chart/plot properties using the axis instance `axes`.

**Doing it your way using function**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x**2)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

def plot1(ax): # ax now points to ax1
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_title('Sharing Y axis')

def plot2(ax): # ax now points to ax2
    ax.scatter(x, y)    

plot1(ax1) # Pass the first axis instance 
plot2(ax2) # Pass the second axis instance 
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot -- made my day